# C++ Makefile; how to do when there are dependencies between external modules

Tags: c++, makefile, dependency-management

For example, my program uses 2 external modules like below image.

[image: dependencies between external modules]

There are module A and module B.
Module B uses and includes module A inside it; A's headers, library and data(=model).

But their version is different; the version of A in B is 3.6, but the latest version of A is 3.8

My program includes both modules, with my Makefile like below.
However, I got compile error or, my program get segment faults at runtime.

```
g++ -I$(A_PATH)/include -I$(B_PATH)/include \
    -L$(A_PATH)/lib -L$(B_PATH)/lib \
    -Wl,-rpath,$(A_PATH)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(B_PATH)/lib \
    …
```

I'd like to use the latest module A in my program, then,
what is the best way to use these modules in my Makefile?

Comment: "I got unspecified compiler errors while trying to compile undisclosed code". That's not an awful lot of usable information here.

Comment: If you are building module A and/or module B, they are not really external modules. If you don't, makefile cannot ensure you are using compatible versions. Make is not a configuration manager. If you have A v3.8 and B built against A v3.6, you have an unusable configuration. Either switch to A v3.6, or build a version of B against A v3.8 yourself.

Comment: Module A and B are not open source proejcts. I cannot build the library myself; I can just use compiled libraries. Actually, I'd like to check if there was some well-known techniques to solve this problem. Your comment is very helpful for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use different directories.  One for module A v3.8 that your code'll use. Another directory for module B and under that have sub-diretory for module A v3.6.  You can have Makefiles in each of these directories as well as one for you source code (in a separate directory).

Comment: As I mentioned above comment, module A and B are not open source projects, and also they are not my code. I manage my project using git, and I want neither these modules to be included in my project, nor put my Makefiles into these modules' directory. However, if there is no other way, your suggestion seems like a good alternative. I appreciate you answering my question.